# Youtube subscriber count for pericular channel within last month/day/year With youtube API V3

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I can find all the subscriber count of channel using

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=channel_id&key=your_key
```

But i need to find who subscribe my channel in last 3 days,10 days,1 month etc. Is this possible with Youtube V3 API.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you check the documentation for [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) it states.

> Returns a collection of zero or more channel resources that match the request criteria

You can also check all of the parameters that can be supplied there is no way to search for a specific time.

Stats:

Stats on channels are available but the information is very general and will not give you information over time.

```
"statistics": {
    "viewCount": "125646789",
    "commentCount": "393",
    "subscriberCount": "1271986",
    "hiddenSubscriberCount": false,
    "videoCount": "4543"
  }
```

Comment: @DalmTo Thanks for the answer. i have checked that but is there any alternate to find that. because i have seen other website that shows the statistic of channels like howmany views/subscribe/watch etc as date wise.

Comment: They are probably part of the Youtube partner program which gives them access to the partner api which has a lot more power than the normal youtube data api.  https://developers.google.com/youtube/partner/  Google has several apis that are not available to the general public.

Comment: So how we become a part of partner program?

Comment: you have a channel with a few million subscribers and Google will contact you.

Comment: @DakmTo But i need a statistics for the authenticated users. not only for my channel. Like which channel is authenticate with us we need its all statistic. so is there any possibility for that?

Comment: @IshanShah I understand that you want to do something but that doesnt mean that the API you are using is going to let you do it.   As developers we are limited to what these third party apis allow us to do.  Sadly our imagination and the instructions from others tends to go beyond these limitations.